# why is this php fatal error message showing?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'm a novice PHP programmer and not so knowledgeable abouts bits and bytes, and I was wondering why this message even shows up:

> **Fatal error:** Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in **D:\xampp1.8.3\htdocs\hkmschat\default.php** on line **227**

I know my website is very large, but it loads fast enough, and it would be a pain to change it.

I was wondering, why is allocating 40 bytes too much when the allowed memory size is 134217728 bytes (128 megabytes). Can somebody help me with the meaning of "the allowed memory size" and "allocated memory". Again, I don't know much about these.

I've also changed `php.ini`'s `memory_limit` value to "256M", but it didn't work then. the error just changed to

> **Fatal error:** Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40 bytes) in **D:\xampp1.8.3\htdocs\hkmschat\default.php** on line **227**

Can somebody please inform me on what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you have a memory leak somewhere. We can't know without some code.

Comment: it's very long, and I don't want to paste the whole thing here

Comment: 134217728 B == 128 MB. You *could* throw more RAM at this problem until you run out of RAM, or you could address the fact that your code is using *way* more memory than it probably should. Anyhow, did you restart your web server after changing php.ini?

Comment: what do you mean? shouldn't it be fine restarting? I didn't have problems.

Comment: You can use `memory_get_usage` in your php file on several places to see where you are using all that memory (and not freeing it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trying to JUST allocate 40 bytes. You already have 128Megs of stuff loaded into memory, and it is trying to then load 40 bytes more. This puts you over the limit, and you get the fatal error.  As for the php.ini, there are several versions of php.ini that could be being used. you should use a test page and use a `phpinfo();` call to determine that you are modifying the correct php.ini.

Comment: "I've also changed php.ini's memory_limit value to "512M", but it didn't work then."   If I am interpreting this correclty, you are saying the page stopped working when you gave it more memory. This leads me to believe you may have some kind of loop in your code that needs lots of memory, maybe an infinite loop(infinity is a lot). Post some code for more help.

Comment: yeah - I have a lot of loops in the area - maybe one is infinite.

Comment: yeah, that was the problem. Thanks!